# SELECT … WHERE without FROM throws syntax error

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.5.38, and I was trying to generate a result with zero rows with `SELECT`.

Using the nonexistent `DUAL` table, it works:

```
SELECT 123 FROM DUAL WHERE FALSE
```

But the plain version gives syntax error:

```
SELECT 123 WHERE FALSE
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE FALSE' at line 1

Is it a MySQL bug or I missed something?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d41d8/1028

Comment: `FROM` clause is necessary

Comment: @diEcho: `SELECT 1` is a valid query, I was just curious if you can toggle between returning 0 or 1 rows using `WHERE`.

Comment: MySQL does not support this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find that syntax as [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) so it's technically unsupported:

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
      [PARTITION partition_list]
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
        [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
        export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

As you can see, `FROM` is optional but `WHERE` requires `FROM`:

```
[FROM table_references
      [PARTITION partition_list]
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

In any case, it doesn't seem particularly useful to print a row and immediately filter it out, does it?

> It might be useful for unioning multiple similar selects

That's a different query, thus a different syntax... with `FROM` ;-)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 123 AS foo
    UNION
    SELECT 456
    UNION
    SELECT 789
) data
WHERE foo<>456
```

If you merely append a plain WHERE at the end you'd only be filtering the last SELECT.

Comment: It might be useful for unioning multiple similar selects. Actually I just tested something, and found it weird. Also, I didn't catch that the `[FROM …` does't have a closing `]` at the line end, now it's understandable.

Comment: +100 in fact this is very useful. Thank for sharing this much of information.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html):

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
    [PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
    [INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
        [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
        export_options
      | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
      | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
    [FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

And note that, whilst `FROM` *is* optional, all of the successive features are contained within the `[]` block that is around the `FROM` - if you want to use any of those features, you need a `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue myself when trying to conditionally insert rows into a table using a single query. Being able to INSERT/WHERE is quite useful, but not being able to do so without a FROM clause is somewhat odd, coming from MSSQL where this is possible. I got around it by selecting from a subquery that returns only one record:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_1, column_2)
SELECT 'Value 1', 'Value 2'
FROM (SELECT 1 AS whocares) AS t
WHERE ....
```

Comment: I guess the subquery is instantly optimised away. Maybe instead of `WHERE`, `HAVING` could work without tables, but I'm lazy to test it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Now, in the year 2021, your question can be answered with a **YES**, it's possible. Using [MySQL Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html).

Your example would be then:

```
WITH foo AS (SELECT 123)
SELECT *
FROM   foo
WHERE  false;
```

With CTE you can create pretty complex statements. In my case it helped me also to create a `SELECT` without a `FROM` but with a `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT column FROM TABLE WHERE column = 'FALSE'
```

Comment: This doesn't work in MySQL, probably only in Oracle.

Comment: In mySQL - "TRUE" and "FALSE" are synonyms for TINYINT(1).

Comment: The "DUAL" table doesn't exist in MySQL.

Comment: you are correct, but based on op snippet i provided this answer.

Comment: @Electrosa: While `DUAL` table indeed nonexistent in MySQL, the docs says "DUAL is purely for the convenience of people who require that all SELECT statements should have FROM and possibly other clauses. MySQL may ignore the clauses. MySQL does not require FROM DUAL if no tables are referenced." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score -1):

`FROM DUAL` is a from oracle database. in MySQL you can just drop the from altogether

```
SELECT 123
```

or

```
SELECT now()
```

for example.

Comment: Not helpful. This only works without WHERE clause (which this thread is explicitly about). SELECT ... FROM DUAL WHERE ... works in recent MySQL and MariaDB versions.